# Passing parameters in body of Moodle

Tags: moodle

Currently I am trying to integrate an existing Moodle installation with a separate system that I have developed in house. I have absolutely no experience with moodle however

Assuming that the Moodle user will always be present in the other system is there a way that I can redirect to an external site from moodle while passing a parameter from the current user eg: UserID. so that the redirect looks something like this: http://(mysitename).com/home?UserId=(Current User ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exactly do you want to redirect? After user enters valid credentials? It sounds like auth module then. If you want it somewhere else, like simple link on the moodle frontpage, it will not require any coding. But of course you should alter your external system and code its receiving end, so you should basically develop web-service.

Comment: Thanks, I was working from the wrong end basically, trying to set moodle to pass what I wanted instead of using what moodle has and changing my web service to suit it.